# Is there a way to get a list of all the releases in a GitHub repository?

Tags: python, github, github-api

I believe the `PyGitHub` libary can do this, but for the purposes of my project, I am calling the GitHub API directly with the `requests` library as I am caching the results of my API call with the [`requests-cache`](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#list-releases--parameters) for the `per_page` parameter, the maximum number of releases you can retrieve is 100, but if I am dealing with a repository with over 100, how can I still get a list of all of them? Example code below.

```
import requests

ACCESS_TOKEN = '<insert token>'

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token ' + ACCESS_TOKEN,
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'
}

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/{insert author}/{insert repository}/releases?per_page=100', headers={'Authorization': 'token ' + ACCESS_TOKEN})

print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Github API uses [pagination](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/traversing-with-pagination) to deal with large numbers of responses. You can request pages other than the first page by appending `page=<n>` to your request url. For example:

```
page = 1
while True:
    response = requests.get(
        f"https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo}/releases?per_page=100&page={page}",
        headers={"Authorization": "token " + ACCESS_TOKEN},
    )
    releases = response.json()
    if not releases:
        break
    print(json.dumps(releases, indent=2))
    page += 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to merge all the results into a single JSON string as, if I'm not mistaken, this just prints the results of all the pages separately?

Comment: It does, and of course you can do whatever you want with the results. They're just lists, so you can of course repeatedly `extend` an existing list.